# How to preserve imported CA certificates through Java updates on windows?

Tags: java, ssl, tomcat8, keytool

I've a windows server. I'm running my application using Tomcat 8 and I've installed COMODO SSL on using java keytool. Everytime I update Java, certificates and cacerts get deleted from jre\bin path. Is there a way to preserve these files even after Java update?

Comment: ha! never thought about that... good question